# String literal and removing unwanted characters

Tags: java, string-literals, replaceall

I have a question about removing unwanted character, or in a better sense, keep only certain ones. I have stumbled upon something called String literal and I don't understand how it can help me with achieving my goal. I stumbled upon this somewhere before but don't understand how to use it.

> The String literal "[^\p{Alpha}-']" may be used to match any
>   character that is NOT alphabetic, a dash, or apostrophe; you may find
>   this useful when using replaceAll()

I understand what **replaceAll()** does, but other things I don't understand are the little *codes* like `[a-zA-Z]` that you can use in it and where to look to find more of them. So I pretty much want to do what the quotes says, and only keep the letters and some punctuation.

Comment: For that you got to learn regular expressions..try google it

Comment: A "String literal" is anything inside quote marks.  This particular string literal is used as a _regular expression_, or _regex_ for short.  Google "java tutorial regex" and you can find out what all the codes mean.  Or visit  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html.

Answer (score 0):

The process you are describing is called *Regular Expressions* or regex for short. It's a tool implemented in many programming languages (including Java) which allows you to handle strings with one line of code, which would otherwise be more complicated and annoying.

I suggest this link for a more in depth [tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html).

Answer (score 0):

`replaceAll()` uses **regexes**.

There's too much to explain in a single post, but I will explain a little.

Here's a regex: `[^A-Za-z.?!]`

- `[]` signifies a character class. It will match one of the contained characters (as modified by meta-characters).
- `^` When this is the first character in a char class, it is a meta-character meaning NOT.
- `A-Z` signifies a range. Anything between those ASCII/Unicode values will be matched
- The `.`, `?`, `!` are treated as literals (in other contexts they can become meta-characters).

So, the regex, if quoted and put in a `replaceAll()` will change everything that's not alphabetic,  `.`, `?`, or `!`.

---

The second parameter in `replaceAll()` also accepts some special regex-related characters, like `$1` does not literally mean `$1`.

You'll need to learn about more advanced regex things (capture groups) before you use `$1`.

Comment: do do I place the regex into quotation marks when I put it into replaceAll()?

Comment: @DurpBurger Yes, and you'd need to escape any characters that need to be escaped in strings. It's a pain when the regex needs \ for its own escape (meaning you need to escape the escape), so I'll sometimes paste it into an online tester that auto-escapes everything.